# Checkmark in a tableview, only one selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Hi I know how to add a tick mark on each row when you select it, but how can you only allow ONE to be ticked ?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.CityTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.CityTableView setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [self.CityTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

this does it for every one, but I want it to remove the last one and add the new one when another one is pressed.

thanks

Comment: Keep a list of what is selected then only allow selection is that list is empty. Or use a BOOL.

Comment: You are deselecting the current tapped cell and then add checkmark to it.
Do you have multiple selection set on the table ?If so , set it to NO 
and in deselectRowAtIndexPath remove the checkmark from the cell

Comment: Close to what @CW0007007 said, keep the list but simply unselect whatever is in that list before selecting the new one (his comment would not allow you to change selection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance variable as `NSIndexPath *selectedIndex;`

In your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Your cell Initialization here

    cell.accessoryType = [indexPath isEqual:selectedIndex] ?UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      NSIndexPath * prevIndexPath = selectedIndex;

      selectedIndex = indexPath;

      [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:prevIndexPath, indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to reload the whole table just for one/two cell.
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:yourArrayWithCellsToReload withRowAnimation:someAnimation] can be used